# send SMS using sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ole, ole-automation

I am trying to send SMS using a web api from sql server. I have error in `sp_OAMethod`. Below written is the code for the same

```
DECLARE @iReq int,@hr int 
DECLARE @sUrl as varchar(500) 
DECLARE @errorSource VARCHAR(8000) 
DECLARE @errorDescription VARCHAR(8000) 

-- Create Object for XMLHTTP
EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP', @iReq OUT 
PRINT @hr

IF @hr <> 0 
BEGIN

Raiserror('sp_OACreate Microsoft.XMLHTTP FAILED!', 16, 1)


SET @sUrl='http://alerts.ebensms.com/api/v3/?method=sms&api_key=******&to=#MobNo#&sender=XXXX&message=#Msg#'
SET @sUrl=REPLACE(@sUrl,'#MobNo#','0000000000') 
SET @sUrl=REPLACE(@sUrl,'#Msg#','Thanks') 
SELECT @sUrl 

---- sms code start

EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iReq, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @sUrl,true
PRINT @hr 
END

IF @hr <> 0 
Raiserror('sp_OAMethod Open FAILED!', 16, 1) 

EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iReq, 'send' 
SELECT @iReq 
PRINT 'open failed'

IF @hr <> 0 
  BEGIN
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @iReq, @errorSource OUTPUT, @errorDescription OUTPUT 
SELECT [Error Source] = @errorSource, 
[Description] = @errorDescription Raiserror('sp_OAMethod Send FAILED!', 16, 1) 
  END

ELSE
BEGIN
EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @iReq,'responseText'
PRINT @hr 
INSERT INTO tblUnCandidateSendSMSLog (Id,mobile,sendtext,created) values  (12,'0000000000','send','AAAAAAA-B23C80FD16D4')
END


EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo
```

Comment: It is unlikely that anyone will attempt to debug your code. Try it yourself first - and post the complete text of any error message.

Comment: Using `sp_OACreate` and never calling `sp_OADestroy` is a recipe for memory leaks and server instability. Writing code that handles all errors correctly and still does this is not trivial. In general, if you're using `sp_OACreate`, you're probably *doing it wrong* because you should be writing client code that does the thing that is not SQL. SQL is the thing SQL Server is for, it's what it's good at, and using it to call web services is a Bad Idea.

Comment: Using `sp_OACreate` is a bad idea. There are other ways to send SMS's. At least indicate what line the error occurs on and what the error is

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I accept that sp_OACreate is a bad idea. Its a requirement that I am trying to figure out. If it were any other means of sending SMS, I can use any api or during the registration process.

Comment: Here @hr <> 0 is 0 and the send method fails in this code.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert Thank you for the suggestion to use sp_OADestroy. I have implemented this in my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in relation to

```
sp_OAMethod @iReq, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @sUrl,true
```

where in it said send failed.

The issue is now resolved by

```
sp_OAMethod @iReq, 'Open', NULL, 'POST', @sUrl,false
```

and changing

```
sp_OACreate 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP', @iReq OUT
```

to

```
sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @iReq OUT;
```

Comment: Thanks for returning with an answer. In future please actually indicate the line with the error and any error message in your question

Comment: Sure @nick, I will do the same